# Synchronizing physics thread with AnimationTimer

Tags: multithreading, javafx

**Problem**

A physics thread is writing into a common data structure. The AnimationTimer renders the data of the common data structure. The physics thread runs at 30fps, the AnimationTimer at 60fps.

Obviously you need some kind of synchronization between these two. The AnimationTimer shouldn't use the data of the common data structure while the physics thread is writing into it. And vice versa.

**Question**

What's the preferred way to synchronize the physics thread with the AnimationTimer?

The obvious way would be to use multiple data structures. But the problem remains: How do you properly synchronize which data structure either of them is using without blocking the fx thread?

**Code**

Here's some code in case anyone wants to toy around. It's a dummy implementation in which a physics thread and a renderer access the same data structure. Each physics frame a new data point is added. Each renderer frame all data points are painted on a canvas. A log line is written each time they conflict per render frame.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    double sceneWidth = 640;
    double sceneHeight = 480;

    Canvas canvas;

    /**
     * The data structure is filled in the physics thread, used in the render thread 
     * Values: 0 = don't paint pixel, 1 = paint pixel
     */
    double[] commonDataStructure = new double[(int) (sceneWidth * sceneHeight)];

    /**
     * True when the physics thread is performing its calculations and writing data to the common data structure
     */
    boolean isPhysicsThreadWritingData = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // create canvas to paint on
        canvas = new Canvas( sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
        root.setCenter(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        startPhysics();
        startRender();

    }

    /**
     * Physics thread running at 30fps
     */
    private void startPhysics() {

        Thread physicsThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            double physicsFps = 1000f / 30f;
            int physicsFrameCount = 0; // counter used for adding new data point per physics frame

            @Override
            public void run() {

                long prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (true) {

                    currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // run only at required physics fps
                    if ((currTime - prevTime) >= physicsFps) {

                        physicsFrameCount++;

                        if( physicsFrameCount > commonDataStructure.length) {
                            physicsFrameCount = 0;
                        }

                        // perform physics calculations
                        calculatePhysicsData( physicsFrameCount);

                        prevTime = currTime;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        physicsThread.setDaemon(true);
        physicsThread.start();

    }

    /**
     * Render loop
     */
    private void startRender() {

        AnimationTimer renderLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // render on canvas using the physics data
                renderUsingPhysicsData();

            }
        };

        renderLoop.start();

    }

    /**
     * Dummy physics implementation which adds a new data point at every frame
     * @param physicsFrameCount
     */
    private void calculatePhysicsData( int physicsFrameCount) {

        isPhysicsThreadWritingData = true;

        for( int i=0; i < commonDataStructure.length; i++) {

            if( i < physicsFrameCount) {
                commonDataStructure[ i] = 1;
            } else {
                commonDataStructure[ i] = 0;
            }

        }

        isPhysicsThreadWritingData = false;

    }

    /**
     * Dummy render implementation which reads the common data and paints it (as single pixel) on a canvas.
     */
    private void renderUsingPhysicsData() {

        // log only once per frame to avoid flood logging
        boolean isConflictLogged = false;

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // clear screen
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        // paint
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        for( int i=0; i < commonDataStructure.length; i++) {

            // check if we are rendering data that are being modified
            if( isPhysicsThreadWritingData && !isConflictLogged) {
                System.err.println( "Physics thread is writing while data are still being rendered");
                isConflictLogged = true;
            }

            double x = i % sceneWidth;
            double y = i / sceneWidth;

            if( commonDataStructure[i] != 0) {
                gc.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-level synchronization is tricky to get right. For example, you need to make `isPhysicsThreadWritingData` `volatile` (or synchronize access to it) to read and write it from different threads in order to ensure both threads will see the correct "live" value. The best quick overview for this (IMO) is the concurrency sections in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*.

It's better to use higher-level API whenever possible. I would recommend, if possible, making your data structure immutable creating an [atomic wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) for it. For example:

```
public class PhysicalState {

    private final double[] data ;

    public PhysicalState(double[] data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    public double[] getData() {
        double[] dataCopy = new double[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataCopy, 0, data.length);
        return dataCopy ;
    }

    public int getNumberOfDataPoints() {
        return data.length;
    }

}
```

Then you can modify your code as follows:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference ;

public class Main extends Application {

    int sceneWidth = 640;
    int sceneHeight = 480;

    Canvas canvas;

    /**
     * The data structure is filled in the physics thread, used in the render thread 
     * Values: 0 = don't paint pixel, 1 = paint pixel
     */

    AtomicReference<PhysicalState> state = new AtomicReference<>(new PhyiscalState(new double[sceneWidth * sceneHeight]));


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // create canvas to paint on
        canvas = new Canvas( sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
        root.setCenter(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        startPhysics();
        startRender();

    }

    /**
     * Physics thread running at 30fps
     */
    private void startPhysics() {

        Thread physicsThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            double physicsFps = 1000f / 30f;
            int physicsFrameCount = 0; // counter used for adding new data point per physics frame

            @Override
            public void run() {

                long prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (true) {

                    currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // run only at required physics fps
                    if ((currTime - prevTime) >= physicsFps) {

                        physicsFrameCount++;

                        if( physicsFrameCount > state.get().getNumberOfDataPoints()) {
                            physicsFrameCount = 0;
                        }

                        // perform physics calculations
                        calculatePhysicsData( physicsFrameCount);

                        prevTime = currTime;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        physicsThread.setDaemon(true);
        physicsThread.start();

    }

    /**
     * Render loop
     */
    private void startRender() {

        AnimationTimer renderLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // render on canvas using the physics data
                renderUsingPhysicsData();

            }
        };

        renderLoop.start();

    }

    /**
     * Dummy physics implementation which adds a new data point at every frame
     * @param physicsFrameCount
     */
    private void calculatePhysicsData( int physicsFrameCount) {

        double[] newData = new double[state.get().getNumberOfDataPoints()];
        for( int i=0; i < newData.length; i++) {

            if( i < physicsFrameCount) {
                newData[ i] = 1;
            } else {
                newData[ i] = 0;
            }

        }

        state.set(new PhysicalState(newData));

    }

    /**
     * Dummy render implementation which reads the common data and paints it (as single pixel) on a canvas.
     */
    private void renderUsingPhysicsData() {

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // clear screen
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        // paint
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        double[] data = state.get().getData();

        for( int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

            double x = i % sceneWidth;
            double y = i / sceneWidth;

            if( data[i] != 0) {
                gc.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Similarly, you should consider using a [`SceheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to manage running the physics engine 30 times per second.

This is probably the simplest approach, but not necessarily the most performant as there's some array copying that's happening, that could possibly be avoided using other techniques.

Other approaches might involve a "pipeline" with threads putting data into and retrieving data from shared `BlockingQueue`s. For example, you could have your "physics thread" compute the data array and push it to a `BlockingQueue` of size 1, a "canvas generating thread" take from the `BlockingQueue` whenever something is available, create the `Canvas`, and set an `AtomicReference<Canvas>`. Then the `AnimationTimer` just displays the current value of the canvas. SO user @jewelsea has a couple of nice examples of these kinds of approaches [here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5500981) and [here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743).